# combining Jquery, AJAX, and PHP trouble

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple script that uses AJAX to look for changes in a database table, and if a change is detected, return information from that table.

Here is my source: http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/ajax-auto-refresh-volume-ii/#comment-570

I also have this nifty notification banner written in JS/JQ: http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Simple-jQuery-Sticky-Notification-Plugin-Notify-Me.html

I have both working independently,as in, the updater will automatically update the Div, and the notification will activate on button press.

Here is the code for the receiving div of the updater:

```
<div id="message-list" data-counter="<?php echo (int)$db->check_changes();?>">
    <?php echo $db->get_news();?>
</div>
```

As far as I can see, when data-counter changes, then get_news() is called.

Here is get_news() - This is a PHP function defined under a class:

```
function get_news(){
    if($result = $this->dbase->query('SELECT * FROM cmc_log WHERE id<>1 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1')){
        $return = '';
        while($r = $result->fetch_object()){
            $return .= '<p> '.$r->time.' | '.htmlspecialchars($r->message).'</p>';  
        }
        return $return;
    }
}
```

For the notification system I have:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn error"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> Error</a>      
    </div>
</div>

<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/notifyme.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.error').on('click', function(){
        $(this).notifyMe(
            'top',
            'error',
            'Lorem Ipsum Text',
            'Lorem ipsum dolos lorem uisnsnd h jsakdh ajkdbh',
            600
        );
    });
});
</script>
```

I would like the notification banner to be called when news is available, i.e. on get_news() i guess. But I also need to incorporate the output of get_news() in to the actual banner... I think I've gotten myself confused as to what can go where!

Any help appreciated! Thanks,

**An Update!** So, the author of the auto-refresh script posted and reminded me about the AJAX, which of course is the perfect place to trigger.

```
<script>
    /* AJAX request to checker */
    function check(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'checker.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                counter:$('#message-list').data('counter')
            }
        }).done(function( response ) {
            /* update counter */

            $('#message-list').data('counter',response.current);

            /* check if with response we got a new update */

            if(response.update==true){
                $('#message-list').html(response.newsf);
                $('#message-list2').html(response.news);
                //fire notification

                $(this).notifyMe(
'top',
'error',
'Update available:',
response.news.val,
400);

            }
        });
    }
    //Every 10 sec check if there is new update
    setInterval(check,10000);
</script>
```

The last thing I've yet to work out is how to get the value of `$('#message-list2').html(response.news);` as a string in to the notifyMe() call?

**Answered:**
Got it working with this: 
There's probably a neater way than populating a hidden div, but at least it is working now!

```
<script>
    /* AJAX request to checker */
    function check(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'checker.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                counter:$('#message-list').data('counter')
            }
        }).done(function( response ) {
            /* update counter */

            $('#message-list').data('counter',response.current);

            /* check if with response we got a new update */

            if(response.update==true){
                $('#message-list').html(response.newsf);
                $('#message-list2').html(response.news);
                //fire notification

                $(this).notifyMe('top','error','Update available:',document.getElementById('message-list2').innerHTML,400);

            }
        });
    }
    //Every 20 sec check if there is new update
    setInterval(check,10000);
</script>
```

```
Previous alerts:

<div style="padding-left:10px" id="message-list" data-counter="<?php echo (int)$db->check_changes();?>">
    <?php echo $db->get_news_full();?>
</div>

<div style="display: none;" id="message-list2" data-counter="<?php echo (int)$db->check_changes();?>">
    <?php echo $db->get_news();?>
</div>
```

Nick

Comment: So what error are you getting?

Comment: I'm not exactly seeing a question - where are you having trouble?

Comment: I'd recommend to call the subsequent `check`s from within `check.done` since you will continue to build up requests if the connection stalls

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger click when there is a new entry, after ajax is finished and the response.update is true. Something like that:

```
    function check(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'checker.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                counter:$('#message-list').data('counter')
            }
        }).done(function( response ) {
            /* update counter */
            $('#message-list').data('counter',response.current);
            /* check if with response we got a new update */
            if(response.update==true){
                $('#message-list').html(response.news);

                //we have new entries so we want to open the notify thing, so we trigger click, I'm assuming the click is for $('.error')
                $('.error').trigger('click'); 
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Of course! Im getting old news in my notification though and not the latest one!? e.g at http://patientpathfinder.co.uk/superstorefinder_responsive/ticker.php thanks for your quick reply! Glad your live demo is back up ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    /* AJAX request to checker */
    function check(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'checker.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                counter:$('#message-list').data('counter')
            }
        }).done(function( response ) {
            /* update counter */

            $('#message-list').data('counter',response.current);

            /* check if with response we got a new update */

            if(response.update==true){
                $('#message-list').html(response.newsf);
                $('#message-list2').html(response.news);
                //fire notification

                $(this).notifyMe('top','error','Update available:',document.getElementById('message-list2').innerHTML,400);

            }
        });
    }
    //Every 20 sec check if there is new update
    setInterval(check,10000);
</script>
```

```
Previous alerts:

<div style="padding-left:10px" id="message-list" data-counter="<?php echo (int)$db->check_changes();?>">
    <?php echo $db->get_news_full();?>
</div>

<div style="display: none;" id="message-list2" data-counter="<?php echo (int)$db->check_changes();?>">
    <?php echo $db->get_news();?>
</div>
```